# Does 'k' in the rate law change with a change in volume

Tags: rate-equation

I'm a high school AP Chem student and we recently learned about the rate law and the Arrhenius equation. In school, we learned that rate constant 'k' is only changed with temperature or catalyst. However, I saw in my school's textbook that if we look at the Arrhenius equation through a collision model, the frequency factor 'A' can be re-expressed as 'pz', where 'p' is the orientation factor and 'z' is the collision frequency. If this holds true, wouldn't rate constant 'k' be affected by stressors that influence the rate of collision like volume?

The image below is my school's textbook(Chemistry-a molecular approach 4th edition page 647).

[image: My school's textbook]

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  
-----
For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Disclaimer*: It's been a long time since I did this.)

The collision frequency (or *collision density*, to use the term in Atkins' *Physical Chemistry* 9ed) is indeed proportional to concentration. We assume here a bimolecular reaction of the form $\ce{A + B -> P}$. Eq. 22.3a in Atkins writes:

$$Z_\ce{AB} = \sigma \sqrt{\frac{8k_\mathrm{B}T}{\pi\mu}} N_A^2 [\ce{A}][\ce{B}] = \sigma \bar{c}_\text{rel}N_A^2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}].$$

Here, $Z_\ce{AB}$ refers to the collision density between two molecules $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$. $\sigma$ is the collision cross-section (essentially a function of the molecule's shape and size), $\mu$ is the reduced mass $m_\ce{A}m_\ce{B}/(m_\ce{A} + m_\ce{B})$, and $\bar{c}_\text{rel} = \sqrt{8k_\mathrm{B}T/\pi\mu}$ is the mean relative speed of the reactants (i.e. how fast they are moving with respect to one another).

It's, however, strictly incorrect to write that the pre-exponential factor $A$ is proportional to the collision density, otherwise that double-counts the concentration factor in the rate. Indeed, Atkins never writes that $k$ or $A$ are proportional to the collision density. Rather, the *entire rate of reaction* (denoted $v$) is proportional to the collision density $Z_\ce{AB}$, times the probability of effective collisions $\exp(-E_\mathrm{a}/RT)$, times a factor of $1/N_\mathrm{A}$ which isn't physically important (it's just to make sure that our rate is expressed in terms of concentrations):

$$\begin{align}
v &= Z_\ce{AB} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{E_\mathrm{a}}{RT}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{N_\mathrm{A}} \\
&= \sigma \bar{c}_\text{rel}N_A[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{E_\mathrm{a}}{RT}\right) 
\end{align}$$

But we also know that the rate of a bimolecular reaction is given by $v = k[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]$, which allows us to identify an expression for the rate constant $k$:

$$k = \sigma \bar{c}_\text{rel}N_A \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{E_\mathrm{a}}{RT}\right)$$

and hence the pre-exponential factor:

$$A = \sigma \bar{c}_\text{rel}N_A.$$

At some point in this chain of events (it doesn't matter exactly where), the fudge factor $P$ (where $0 < P \leq 1$) is introduced to 'explain' the observation that not all collisions are successful. So, taking this into account, we have that

$$A = P \cdot \sigma \bar{c}_\text{rel}N_A.$$

which is decidedly *not* of the form $A = PZ$. (In fact, it is pretty much $PZ$ but divided through by $N_\mathrm{A}$ and the concentrations of the reacting species.) We might like to think of this as being $A = PZ'$, where $Z'$ is some kind of *scaled collision density* where the concentration factors (and $N_\mathrm{A}$) are removed from the equation, and that would be fine; but it's not right to say $A = PZ$.

Answer (score 4):

The original formulation gives the temperature-dependence of the rates:

[image]
Source: https://zenodo.org/record/1749766#.YhWZ85ZOklw

The given formula is showing the relationship between two rates (same concentration of reactants, different temperature). The pre-exponential factor cancels out here:

$$\sigma_{t_1} = \sigma_{t_1} e^{A \frac{T_1 - T_0}{T_0 T_1}}$$

The $A$ in the formula is $-\frac{E_A}{R}$ in modern formulation. The text roughly translates to:

> Those [reactions] which are investigated at common temperature are obeying the relation of the following form: [formula], where $\sigma_{t_0}$ and $\sigma_{t_1}$ are the reaction rates at two temperatures $t_0$ and $t_1$, $A$ is a constant and $T_0$ and $T_1$ are the respective absolute temperatures.

The collision frequency is introduced in collision theory, also explaining the rate and not the rate constant:

$$r(T) = k n_A n_B = Z \rho \exp\left(-\frac{E_\mathrm{a}}{RT}\right)$$

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory

If you mix and match these without being careful, you get the confusing (and incorrect) statement that the rate constant is concentration dependent. Your textbook is not the only one that is fuzzy about this.

Patrick Fleming uses the following formulation in [Libretext](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(Fleming)/11%3A_Chemical_Kinetics_I/11.10%3A_Collision_Theory):

> $$\text{rate} = Z_{ab} F$$
> $$Z_{AB} = \left( \dfrac{8k_BT}{\pi \mu} \right)^{1/2} \sigma_{AB} [A][B]$$

Here, the equations are only dimensionally correct if the concentration is given as number of molecules per volume, and the rate is given as number of molecules per time. The square-root term has dimensions of length per time (speed), and the cross section is an area. The author mentions that this is for bimolecular reactions only. If you write down the rate law and compare the $k$ from collision theory with that of the Arrhenius equation, you get the following expression for $A$:

> $$A= \left( \dfrac{8k_BT}{\pi \mu} \right)^{1/2} \sigma_{AB}$$

In a historic paper, $Z$ is defined differently (not concentration-dependent):

[image]

Source: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01347a011

So you have to be careful about the order of reaction (because the dimensions of $k$ and $A$ depend on it), and how $Z$ is defined.
In any case, however, the rate constant is not dependent on concentration (or volume).